# Call onchange handler function

Tags: jquery, javascript

I have this `OnChange` function:

```
$("select[id^=type]").change(function(){/*...*/});
```

The question is: How can I call this from the following function:

```
$("#all_db").change(function()
{
    /*...*/
    $("select[id^=type]").each.trigger("change"); //I have tried this
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("select[id^='type']").change();
```

is all you need. I would quote the value you pass to the `startsWith` selector.

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare the function separately. In your example you are saying to JQuery to trigger the function change when it is the time. Nevertheless, such a function doesn't exist. To do it try to declare your function as a separate one. Like this:

```
function myDesiredFunc(){ /*console.log("Inside it");*/ }
$("#all_db").change(myDesiredFunc);
$("select[id^=type]").change(myDesiredFunc);
```

Note that I commented console.log because this will only work if you have firebug installed.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

`$("select[id^=type]").trigger("change");`

should do the trick. Otherwise, that one should:

```
$("select[id^=type]").each(function(i){
 $(this).trigger("change");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

See [this](http://api.jquery.com/change/)  :

```
$("#all_db").change(function()
{
    /*...*/
    $("select[id^=type]").change();
});
```

Usually in Jquery , the same name to create a trigger , runs to fire it.

Answer (score 0):

`$('select').change();` then you can do `$('select[id='yourIdHere']').change();` or whatever you want.